# Moli Player Pro - subtitles not working

Tags: apps

I bought Moli Player Pro today and wanted to watch a movie which had subtitles in .txt file. After I launched video, the player popped up that it found subtitles file. Obviously I clicked yes, but nothing happened. I checked in a PC and it worked with no problems. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Contact the company who made the app and ask them?

Comment: I'm asking here to know whether anyone had this problem before. I'm sure someone had.

Comment: It does sound like a bug which should be reported :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar experience. Make sure your subtitle file has the same name as the video file. For example if your file name is testvideo.avi your subtitle file should be testvideo.avi.srt.

Also, you need to change the default language of subtitles (I guess it's "English (United States)") to English (or required language) from the settings.

http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-apps/252060-help-needed-moliplayer-subtitles.html#post2240290